# Parsing issue android widget to int

Tags: java, android, parsing

Need help parsing, I have tried "porting" my dice roller project to Android using Android Studio, I have most of the controller values replaced with their android widget counterparts, one problem, I am not sure how to properly parse widget values to an Int. I have marked them with aligned left comments below.

modifier is an EditText
result is a TextView

I have tried many combinations and this is the most recent.
 The one that worked when it was pure java was `.getValue().toString().trim()` but I cannot use `.getValue` why is this?

```
public void onStart()
{
   super.onStart();
   percentile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
     @Override
     public void onClick (View v)
     {
       {
          //issue is here
          int total = Nat20_core.roll10(cumulative.isChecked(),
                        Integer.parseInt (String.valueOf(modifier)),
                        Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(result)));
          //end issue
          result.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        }
      }
    });
}
```

I have also tried this in a previous program as 
set

Comment: what is your problem you are facing?

Comment: Please take some time and review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then format your question

Comment: Re-Formated the question, sorry about the previous content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no `.getValue()` method for EditText and TextView widget.

For EditText, you can use [getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) which returns an `Editable`. So, you need to get the string from it using `toString()`. So, you will need to use:

```
modifier.getText().toString();
```

For TextView, you can use [getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) which returns a `CharSequence`. You also need to get the string from it using `toString()`. So, you can use the above line too:

```
result.getText().toString();
```

Now, you need to convert the following code:

```
int total = Nat20_core.roll10(cumulative.isChecked(),
                        Integer.parseInt (String.valueOf(modifier)),
                        Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(result)));
```

to:

```
int total = Nat20_core.roll10(cumulative.isChecked(),
                        Integer.parseInt (modifier.getText().toString()),
                        Integer.parseInt(result.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Oh! thanks a lot.I have tried your recommended code however the app keeps crashing and I'm not sure why. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: the problem probably in your `Nat20_core.roll10()` method. Be aware that parsing a non-numeric String with `parseInt` will throw an error.

Comment: Boolean int int is what is needed to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

In EditText and TextView, the "value" is "text":

Integer.parseInt(modifier.getText().toString())